# How do I filter list of items having data-rel tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we use jQuery to filter the list of items below based on selected option from drop-down list?

Each of the items has a data-rel tag

```
<select id="lstkbCategory" data-placeholder="Choose a Category">
    <option> --show all-- </option>
    <option>close</option>
    <option>general</option>
    <option>verification</option>
    <option>welcome</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="kb-items">
    <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="verification">xxx</a>
    <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="close">xxx</a>
    <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="welcome">444</a>
    <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="welcome">aaa</a>
    <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="general">bbb</a>
    <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="general">ggg</a>
    <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="general">qqq</a>
    <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="general">sos</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$("#lstkbCategory").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $(".kb-items .kb-item").show();

    if (value !== '-- show all --') { $(".kb-items .kb-item[data-rel !='" + value + "']").hide(); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector like this:

```
var $relElements = $("[data-rel='" + selectedOption + "']");
```

(more about attribute selectors here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

There is also a filter method which you can use to narrow down an element-group:

```
$(".kb-item").filter("[data-rel='" + selectedOption + "']");
```

(https://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#lstkbCategory').change(function() {

  var value = $('option:selected', this).text();//get the text of selected option

  $('.kb-items a').filter(function(i, v) {
    $(v).removeClass('red')
    return $(v).attr('data-rel') == value//compare the option with the data-rel



  }).addClass('red')//addClass to anchor with matching data-rel to value

})
```

```css
.red {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lstkbCategory" data-placeholder="Choose a Category">
  <option>--show all--</option>
  <option>close</option>
  <option>general</option>
  <option>verification</option>
  <option>welcome</option>
</select>
<br>
<div class="kb-items">
  <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="verification">xxx</a>
  <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="close">xxx</a>
  <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="welcome">444</a>
  <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="welcome">aaa</a>
  <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="general">bbb</a>
  <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="general">ggg</a>
  <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="general">qqq</a>
  <a class="kb-item" href="#" data-rel="general">sos</a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, please can you alter this to actually filter/ hide the items?

Comment: change the class red to `display none` @CharlesOkwuagwu

Comment: Thanks again. please why do you choose to use removeClass as compared to  `$(".kb-items .kb-item").hide();
  $(".kb-items .kb-item[data-rel='" + val + "']").show()`, suggested in another answer?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu remove class will show the element which is not matching the filter